# css divide div into four equal parts with padding

Tags: css, html

i have a content div, and in there i would like a have four equal div's depending
on the page's width and height.

currently this is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<div class='A' id="none" data-panel_type="none">
    <textarea id="1" name="none"></textarea>
</div>
<div class='B' id="none" data-panel_type="none">
    <textarea id="2" name="none"></textarea>
</div>
<div class='C' id="none" data-panel_type="none">
    <textarea id="3" name="none"></textarea>
</div>
<div class='D' id="none" data-panel_type="none">
    <textarea id="4" name="none"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    border: 2px solid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    left: -15px;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  #content .A {
    border: 2px solid;
    width:50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: purple;
  }

  #content .B {
    border: 2px solid;
    width:50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: purple;
  }

  #content .C {
    border: 2px solid;
    width:50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: purple;
  }

  #content .D {
    border: 2px solid;
    width:50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: purple;
  }
```

what do i need to change to it in order to work? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use `box-sizing` property (further information on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing)), adding

```
#content, #content > div {
    -webkit-box-sixing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

see http://jsbin.com/egukon/1/edit

Comment: This is the only correct answer. The OP stated he wants "four equal divs" (so, quarters based on his CSS), not that he wants four divs of equal width on one row. Worth noting too that there's no need to declare `width: 100%` on a `div`: it will by default use the existing space.

Comment: this gives me one giant div

Comment: no this will give you 4 divs : top-right, top-left, bottom-right and bottom-left all of same height and width as you asked in your question. If this is not what you meant, please post a screenshot of desired result.

Comment: Your code works perfectly, But if the contents of DIVs are different in size, it is displayed unevenly. For example, when a div has just a word 'name', and the second div has a graph... If you have any idea how to resolve this, kindly tell.

Comment: of course my answer addresses this specific problem: open your own question providing a fiddle :)

Comment: Its exactly the same... it has too many code in it  like tables and charts:/ - I mean the logic of page division is exactly the same as you have given.

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
#content {
    border: 2px solid;
    position: relative;   
    float:left;
    width:100%
  }

  #content div {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    height: 50%;
    background: purple;
    display:inline-block;
  }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/psh4u/1/)**

Comment: ok this divides it into 4 equal parts over the length, but i want it to be width and height...

Comment: a square of four smaller squares

Answer (score 0):

You have your `content div width` which is equal to `100%`.

So if you have 4 div in it, you need to set your width for `content A, B, C, D` to `25%`.

Because `25%*4 = 100%`

Maybe add the property `display:inline` to `content A, B, C, D`

Answer (score 0):

All your `div` must be `25%` wide if you want them to fit into the container and feel free to make use of `box-sizing: border-box;` so that the borders of the child divs gets contained inside the width/height. [Working demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/dxqlhmyv).

Answer (score 0):

use flex property in your html

#content
   {
   Your css property
   display:flex;
   }

this will equally divide your sub division tags inside the main division tag in width and height.